# Instance Norm: ValueError: Expected more than 1 spatial element when training, got input size torch.Size([128, 512, 1, 1])

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, resnet, batch-normalization

I have a ResNet-18 working well. Now, I want to use InstanceNorm as normalization layer instead of BatchNorm, so I changed all the batchnorm layers in this way:

```
resnet18.bn1 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)

resnet18.layer1[0].bn1 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer1[0].bn2 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer1[1].bn1 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer1[1].bn2 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)

resnet18.layer2[0].bn1 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer2[0].bn2 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer2[1].bn1 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer2[1].bn2 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer2[0].downsample[1] = nn.InstanceNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)

resnet18.layer3[0].bn1 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer3[0].bn2 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer3[1].bn1 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer3[1].bn2 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer3[0].downsample[1] = nn.InstanceNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)

resnet18.layer4[0].bn1 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer4[0].bn2 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer4[1].bn1 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer4[1].bn2 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
resnet18.layer4[0].downsample[1] = nn.InstanceNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)


resnet18.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=10, bias=True)
```

All the `num_features` are equal to the BatchNorm2d ones, I just changed BatchNorm2d into InstanceNorm2d. So my ResNet-18 is this:

```
ResNet(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
  (bn1): InstanceNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (maxpool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (layer1): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): InstanceNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): InstanceNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): InstanceNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): InstanceNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (layer2): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): InstanceNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): InstanceNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (downsample): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
        (1): InstanceNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): InstanceNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): InstanceNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (layer3): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): InstanceNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): InstanceNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (downsample): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
        (1): InstanceNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): InstanceNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): InstanceNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (layer4): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): InstanceNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): InstanceNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (downsample): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
        (1): InstanceNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): InstanceNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): InstanceNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.9, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
  (fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

I have the error in title. Do you know how can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

I was using CIFAR-10 with size 32x32. If I resize the images to 64x64 It works. This because resnet-18 reduces the filters to 1x1 and as the title says, InstanceNorm wants dimensions (H and W) > 1